# Images under "image/subfolder" cannot be found in the latest Razor Engine - MVC.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am having a hard time in making images in my MVC.NET web application developed in Visual Studio 2012. To keep the story short, please take a look at the following two lines of code:

```
<img src=@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/construct/images/MyPic1.png") />
<img src=@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/construct/images/blog/MyPic2.png") />
```

Both MyPic1.png and MyPic2.png files do exist. However when rendering the page, the first picture which is MyPic1.png is shown but the second one which is found under "blog" subfolder does not show up. I used FireBug and it did not show any error messages!

What could be wrong and how to resolve it?

Comment: If you browse to the URL that FireBug gives you, do you see the image?

Comment: Why not just use `<img src="/Content/themes/construct/images/blog/MyPic2.png" />`?

Comment: Same result is produced. No difference basically.

Comment: Unsure if this would cause your issue, but you need to be sure to enclose the img src url in quotation marks - <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/construct/images/blog/MyPic2.png")" />

Comment: @MetroSmurf, because you should never hardcode urls in an ASP.NET MVC application. This code will break as soon as you deploy the application in a virtual directory in IIS.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov, thanks Darin. I never deploy MVC apps to a virtual directory; good to know.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with your razor code, I did create the folder structure as you mentioned, both the images are loading as expected.

I suspect you might not have the correct file extension.

Explore the file, click Organize -> select Folder and search option -> select File (tab) -> uncheck 'Hide Extension for known file types' as given in below diagram and see the image extension.

[image]

Some time we save image with 'pic1.png.png' or 'pic1.png.jpg'.