# Image rendered correct link, but cannot load the image

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have uploaded a picture to the directory ~\Files\image\C3-E1-B6-74.png, i saved this in the database. Now I'm trying to display this image.

### cshtlm

```
 <img src="@Url.Content(file.FileLink)" alt="test" />
```

When this page is rendered and I check the image tag

```
 <img alt="test" src="C:\Users\thomas\Desktop\Freelauncher1005\Freelauncher\Files\image\C3-E1-B6-74.png">
```

So link is rendered correctly. When I copy this link and paste it in my folderbrowser then it opens the corresponding image.

When searching for this problem I found

[Images under "image/subfolder" cannot be found in the latest Razor Engine - MVC.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15046869/images-under-image-subfolder-cannot-be-found-in-the-latest-razor-engine-mvc)

I checked the extension and everything is correct.

Does anyone has another possible solution?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

```
C:\Users\thomas\Desktop\Freelauncher1005\Freelauncher\Files\image\C3-E1-B6-74.png
```

This type of link will not work in a web browser / page.  You need to have either a relative path from your website root or an absolute path.  Examples:

**Relative Path**

```
<img src="/Files/image/C3-E1-B6-74.png" />
```

**Absolute Path**

```
<img src="http://localhost/Freelauncher/Files/image/C3-E1-B6-74.png"/>
```

I am not sure how you are storing the file information, but if you are including the full file path, this will not work for any type of hosted website.

Answer (score 0):

In the database I saved an absolute path. This is totally wrong, the way to go is save the filename in the database and create a globalvariable where the images are saved for me this is:

```
string path = "~/Files/image/"
```

Then in the razor pages I can call the global variable and past the filename after it...

```
<img src="~/Files/image/@file.FileLink" alt="test" />
```

ASP.net will never search for files / images on your local machine so you always have to work with the relative paths like: ~/Files/image/